# Identifying unique codes in a dataframe that also exist in another smaller dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, lookup

I'm new to python and am playing around with some data. I was able to extract identifier codes with a particular error into a smaller data frame. I would like to remove these records from the larger dataset. However, some of the identifier codes have multiple entries, not all with the error. I would still like to remove all occurrences of identifiers codes where one of the errors occurs.

I'm thinking a for loop approach would be best, but might take a long time as each identifier would have to search through the second list.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this in the best way possible or not - please advise if you have a better idea or approach to removing these records!

Comment: Could you share input data, what have you tried etc.

Comment: At this stage I haven't tried much, just researching a ton. I am able to perform the tasks in excel, but am having trouble translating. Some sample data I guess would be a data frame with the following variables: Code, Age, Occupation with the following values for Code: 0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6; Age: 60, 64, 62, N/A, 77, 88,58, N/A; Occupation: anything (haha). My dataset is much larger than this so it's not as simple as removing codes 2 and 6. I'd like to automate the process. Sorry if this was a bad way of illustrating the question (first time using stackoverflow as well!)

Comment: I have tried creating a subset of the data frame that just contains the codes with errors. I then created a new column in the subset as an identifier of a "bad" code. I was able to get this far and then tried merging the two data frames which is where I get stuck.

Comment: Ok, so you have df1 - columns=Code, Age, Occupation and df2 - columns=Code, and you want to remove all rows from df1 with Code from df2 - is that correct ? Also by dataframe you mean pandas ?

Comment: df2 contains columns for Age and Occupation as well, but that shouldn't matter since we can just specify the Code column, correct? Otherwise, yes that is correct and yes I do mean pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I understand. Roughly this should do the trick for you:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_1=pd.DataFrame(data={"Code": [0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6], "Age": [60, 64, 62, "N/A", 77, 88,58, "N/A", 45]})
>>> df_2=pd.DataFrame(data={"Code": [2,4,5]})
>>> df_1
   Age  Code
0   60     0
1   64     1
2   62     2
3  N/A     2
4   77     3
5   88     4
6   58     5
7  N/A     6
8   45     6
>>> df_3 = df_1.merge(df_2, on="Code", how="left", indicator=True)
>>> df_3
   Age  Code     _merge
0   60     0  left_only
1   64     1  left_only
2   62     2       both
3  N/A     2       both
4   77     3  left_only
5   88     4       both
6   58     5       both
7  N/A     6  left_only
8   45     6  left_only
>>> df_final = df_3[["Age", "Code"]][df_3["_merge"]=="left_only"]
>>> df_final
   Age  Code
0   60     0
1   64     1
4   77     3
7  N/A     6
8   45     6
```

**REF:**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: No worries :) Please up vote, and mark as an answer.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately won't publicly display since I just joined :/